# Set Virtual IP for outgoing traffic?

Tags: linux, centos, linux-networking

I have server with four IP addresses [ 1 parent IP , 3 virtual IPs]. I need to enable route to make appropriate IP address as a outgoing ip address for itself.

IP address list:

```
10.11.12.100
10.11.12.101
10.11.12.102
10.11.12.103
```

Example :

```
10.11.12.100 -->  outgoing traffic through 10.11.12.100
10.11.12.101 -->  outgoing traffic through 10.11.12.101
10.11.12.102 -->  outgoing traffic through 10.11.12.102
10.11.12.103 -->  outgoing traffic through 10.11.12.103
```

I tried the below command, it shows error

> ip route change 10.11.12.101/32 dev eth0 proto  kernel scope link src
>   10.11.12.101
>   RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory

Please someone help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: this is the error message `RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory`

Comment: anyone have chance to check this ?. Still I couldn't fix it.